# Pass Array Into View Codeigniter Mikrotik

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [.id] => *0 [name] => default [as] => 64578 [router-id] => 0.0.0.0 [redistribute-connected] => false [redistribute-static] => false [redistribute-rip] => false [redistribute-ospf] => false [redistribute-other-bgp] => false [out-filter] => [client-to-client-reflection] => true [ignore-as-path-len] => false [routing-table] => [default] => true [disabled] => false ) )
```

> how To loop and pass array above into the view in Codeigniter, please help !

From Comment.

```
if ($this->mikrotikext->mikrotik_connect($ip,$username,$passwor‌​d,$port) == true) { 

    $this->routerosapi->write("/interface/eoip/print",false); 

    $READ = $this->routerosapi->read(false); 

    $data['eoip'] = $this->routerosapi->parseResponse($READ); 

    $this->load->view('mikrotik/interface_eoip', $data); 

    // $this->mikrotik_model->insert_pool($data); 

}
```

Comment: Show your view as well

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's assume for a moment that you store your array to a variable called $myArray. You could then just do the following:

```
$data["myArray"] = $myArray;
$this->load->view("path_to_your_view", $data);
```

The second parameter is sent to you view but it is exploded and every named index in the array becomes it's own variable in the view. So, in the view, you could just:

```
foreach($myArray as $key=>$value){
    echo "<p>$key has a value of $value.</p>";
}
```

That's all there is to it. It's pretty simple...

Comment: thanks for help but an error appears , illegal string offset and array to string conversion

Comment: if ($this->mikrotikext->mikrotik_connect($ip,$username,$password,$port) == true) {
        $this->routerosapi->write("/interface/eoip/print",false);
        $READ = $this->routerosapi->read(false);
        $data['eoip'] = $this->routerosapi->parseResponse($READ);
        $this->load->view('mikrotik/interface_eoip', $data);
        // $this->mikrotik_model->insert_pool($data);
      }

Comment: Where is this error ocurring? In your controller (i.e., the code you pasted) or in the view? If it is in the view, can you post that code where it is failing?

Comment: in controller illegal string offset 'eoip' and in the view undefined variable eoip

Comment: Something is wrong. When you execute $data['eoip'] = something, that is an assignment. It should create the array element. Try this:

unset($data);
$data=array();
$data["eoip"] = <rest of your code>

Comment: in your view you should just access `$data['eoip']` as `$eoip` in case that was the issue. you should really show ALL of the related code!